# Induced map (definition from Munkres that I do not understand)

Tags: general-topology

Right before lemma 46.11, Munkres presents this definition:

Given a function $f: X \times Z \rightarrow Y $, there is a corresponding function $F: Z \rightarrow C(X,Y)$, defined by the equation

$(F(z))(x) = f(x,z)$

Conversely, given $F: Z \rightarrow C(X,Y)$, this equation defines a corresponding function $f: X \times Z \rightarrow Y $. We say that F is the map of Z into $C(X,Y)$ that is $\textbf{induced}$ by f.

The issue I have with this definition is that f apparently does not need to be continuous, yet F gives us continuous functions.

I can actually understand the converse. However, I simply cannot wrap my head around why there must be continuous functions "hidden" in any function of two variables. This is not even a theorem; it's a definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not what the definition claims. This definition is made for the purpose of formulating Theorem 46.11, where $C(X,Y)$ has the compact-open topology, $f$ is continuous, and then $F$ is well-defined and also continuous (and even $F$ continuous implies $f$ continuous for $X$ locally compact Hausdorff).

Munkres does not claim that any $f$ will give a well-defined map $F$ to $C(X,Y)$ (it will always work for $Y^X$), but for the intended application this *will* hold. Don't look for a deeper reason than this.